# Xcode 10 warning: Stale file '/path/to/file' is located outside of the allowed root paths

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

Xcode 10 produces this warning when running `xcodebuild` in a run script phase of a build target. I do this to produce the binary for the other platform (simulator/real device) to lipo into a fat binary for distribution. The warning is produced for every file in the target intermediates directory, for example:

`warning: Stale file '/Users/nick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-ctjxvxdmomwoobfgvvasfhwvcnhy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Library-Target.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sub-Library-Target.build/Objects-normal/i386/Sub-Library-Class.o' is located outside of the allowed root paths.`

What are the root paths? Why is this warning produced? Is there any way I can resolve or suppress it?

Comment: I'm getting the same error building a Contacts.app plugin for macOS 10.14.0 in Xcode 10.0; it should copy the plugin bundle to /~/Library/Address Book Plug-Ins/, but I get this error instead. I'm sure it's connected to the improved security of Mojave, but still, I have to find a way to work around it...

Comment: Did you guys figure something out?

Comment: I realised I didn't need to run xcodebuild in my build phase so I removed it. I don't have a solution to the problem, sorry

Answer (score 45):

I had it on Xcode 11.2

solved it by 
1. Clean (Cmd+Shift+K) and then:

Cmd+Shift+R ( build for Running )

Comment: I did the `clean` then ran my app to a device again, an the nearly 2600 `stale file outside allowed root paths` warnings returned.

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida Let me clarify my above comment.  Before your solution, Xcode takes like 3 minutes to deploy app to a device.  I apply your solution and then after Xcode takes like 15 seconds to deploy....great, I think I have fixed the problem.  But the next time I do a build from CLI again (`cordova build ios`) the build takes 5+ minutes to complete and then all those files are back, causing Xcode deploy to device to take 3+ minutes again.  I think my culprit here is Cordova creating these files to begin with, but I haven't a clue on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you might have copied the .framework to an external path. To solve this annoying warning you should run (as sudo) the command to delete the framework: 
In your case: 
sudo rm -rf /Users/nick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-ctjxvxdmomwoobfgvvasfhwvcnhy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Library-Target.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sub-Library-Target.build/Objects-normal/i386/Sub-Library-Class.o

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Objective-C to create frameworks you may end up with those anoying warnings. The solution I've found is to add

```
-UseModernBuildSystem=NO
```

at end of every **xcodebuild** command in your Run Script.