# NativeScript app gives "warning: Stale file [....appname-Prefix.pch.gch] is located outside of the allowed root paths"

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

If i run the `tns run ios` command for the app I'm developing my console outputs the following:

`warning: Stale file '{pathToFile}/appname-Prefix.pch.gch' is located outside of the allowed root paths`

Since I was wondering whether this was bad I turned to Google for answers. I could only find this:

- The warning is from Xcode
- It's about precompiled headers (I guess for Objective-C)
- ... that are probably misplaced.
- And of course a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52478734/xcode-10-warning-stale-file-path-to-file-is-located-outside-of-the-allowed-r) on Stackoverflow, but not in relation to NativeScript.

I tried to remove the platform (`tns platform remove ios`) and re-adding it. This didn't solve it.

Does anyone know how this file got located outside the allowed root path? 
Can/should I fix this? I really like to understand the technology I'm working with. 
Btw: The `tns build` doesn't give any such warnings.

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Did you find any solution to it

Comment: @FaisalAhmed - did either of you find a solution to this?  Every time I build my app I am getting 2500+ of these messages which adds an enormous amount of time to deploy my app from Xcode.

Comment: No, sorry. Not working with NativeScript anymore.

Comment: Even I am not working on NativeScript