# How to fixe Xcode build error FBLPromises? ( Mac flutter)

Tags: xcode, flutter

How to resolve this error ?

I have the last flutter upgrade, last Xcode 11.5, last MacOS catalina. I have done Xcode 11.5 migration (build phase), move to zsh, selected legacy build system, remove all package not compatible, relaunch pod install by focus the podfile folder with the terminal. Launch flutter clean.
here is my doctor-v

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 1.17.5 at /Users/quentinguichot/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (9 days ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/quentinguichot/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
    ✗ Could not determine java version

 
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.5, Build version 11E608c
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone • 00008030-000448183438802E • ios • iOS 13.3.1

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Here is my error :

```
ld: framework not found FBLPromises
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel

    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

I can run on my device a new projet, with the flutter example, but my projet ( currently in production) who worked fine before all these upgrade, have now this issue...

edit : my podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
   platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.

ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  generated_key_values = {}
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) do |line|
    next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
    plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
    if plugin.length == 2
      podname = plugin[0].strip()
      path = plugin[1].strip()
      podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
      generated_key_values[podname] = podpath
    else
      puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
    end
  end
  generated_key_values
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  
  # Flutter Pod

  copied_flutter_dir = File.join(__dir__, 'Flutter')
  copied_framework_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.framework')
  copied_podspec_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.podspec')
  unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path) && File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
    # Copy Flutter.framework and Flutter.podspec to Flutter/ to have something to link against if the xcode backend script has not run yet.
    # That script will copy the correct debug/profile/release version of the framework based on the currently selected Xcode configuration.
    # CocoaPods will not embed the framework on pod install (before any build phases can generate) if the dylib does not exist.

    generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Generated.xcconfig')
    unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
      raise "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
    end
    generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    cached_framework_dir = generated_xcode_build_settings['FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'];

    unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path)
      FileUtils.cp_r(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.framework'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
    unless File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
      FileUtils.cp(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.podspec'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
  end

  # Keep pod path relative so it can be checked into Podfile.lock.
  pod 'Flutter', :path => 'Flutter'

  # Plugin Pods

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.each do |name, path|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name)
    File.symlink(path, symlink)
    pod name, :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  end
end

# Prevent Cocoapods from embedding a second Flutter framework and causing an error with the new Xcode build system.
#install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     target.build_configurations.each do |config|
       config.build_settings['ARCHS'] = '$ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT'
     end
   end
 end
```

FBLPromises seems to come from an old package I had add ( firebase_ad_mob) I don't know why it take reference while the package is remove ... I clean all, even derivedata and flutter repair cache

Here is error after remove use_framwork!

```
      warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/webview_flutter/webview_flutter.framework' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/webview_flutter/webview_flutter.framework/Headers' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/webview_flutter/webview_flutter.framework/Headers/FLTCookieManager.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/webview_flutter/webview_flutter.framework/Headers/FLTWKNavigationDelegate.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/webview_flutter/webview_flutter.framework/Headers/FLTWebViewFlutterPlugin.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/webview_flutter/webview_flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterWebView.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/webview_flutter/webview_flutter.framework/Headers/JavaScriptChannelHandler.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/webview_flutter/webview_flutter.framework/Headers/webview_flutter-umbrella.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/webview_flutter/webview_flutter.framework/Info.plist' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    ...


...
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/vibration/vibration.framework/vibration' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/unique_identifier/unique_identifier.framework/Headers/unique_identifier-Swift.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/unique_identifier/unique_identifier.framework/Headers/unique_identifier-umbrella.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/unique_identifier/unique_identifier.framework/Info.plist' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/unique_identifier/unique_identifier.framework/Modules/module.modulemap' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/unique_identifier/unique_identifier.framework/Modules/unique_identifier.swiftmodule/Project/arm64-apple-ios.swiftsourceinfo' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/unique_identifier/unique_identifier.framework/Modules/unique_identifier.swiftmodule/Project/arm64.swiftsourceinfo' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/unique_identifier/unique_identifier.framework/Modules/unique_identifier.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftdoc' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/unique_identifier/unique_identifier.framework/Modules/unique_identifier.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/unique_identifier/unique_identifier.framework/Modules/unique_identifier.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftdoc' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/unique_identifier/unique_identifier.framework/Modules/unique_identifier.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/unique_identifier/unique_identifier.framework/unique_identifier' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/shared_preferences/shared_preferences.framework' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/shared_preferences/shared_preferences.framework/Headers' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/shared_preferences/shared_preferences.framework/Headers/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/shared_preferences/shared_preferences.framework/Headers/shared_preferences-umbrella.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/shared_preferences/shared_preferences.framework/Info.plist' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/shared_preferences/shared_preferences.framework/Modules/module.modulemap' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/shared_preferences/shared_preferences.framework/shared_preferences' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/sensors/sensors.framework' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/sensors/sensors.framework/Headers' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/sensors/sensors.framework/Headers/FLTSensorsPlugin.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/sensors/sensors.framework/Headers/sensors-umbrella.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/sensors/sensors.framework/Info.plist' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/sensors/sensors.framework/Modules/module.modulemap' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/sensors/sensors.framework/sensors' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_rounded_progress_bar/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.framework' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_rounded_progress_bar/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.framework/Headers' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_rounded_progress_bar/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.framework/Headers/FlutterRoundedProgressBarPlugin.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_rounded_progress_bar/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.framework/Headers/flutter_rounded_progress_bar-Swift.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_rounded_progress_bar/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.framework/Headers/flutter_rounded_progress_bar-umbrella.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_rounded_progress_bar/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.framework/Info.plist' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_rounded_progress_bar/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.framework/Modules/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.swiftmodule/Project/arm64-apple-ios.swiftsourceinfo' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_rounded_progress_bar/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.framework/Modules/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.swiftmodule/Project/arm64.swiftsourceinfo' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_rounded_progress_bar/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.framework/Modules/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftdoc' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_rounded_progress_bar/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.framework/Modules/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_rounded_progress_bar/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.framework/Modules/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftdoc' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_rounded_progress_bar/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.framework/Modules/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_rounded_progress_bar/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.framework/Modules/module.modulemap' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_rounded_progress_bar/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.framework/flutter_rounded_progress_bar' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.framework' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.framework/Headers' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.framework/Headers/FlutterEmailSenderPlugin.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.framework/Headers/flutter_email_sender-Swift.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.framework/Headers/flutter_email_sender-umbrella.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.framework/Info.plist' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.framework/Modules/flutter_email_sender.swiftmodule/Project/arm64-apple-ios.swiftsourceinfo' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.framework/Modules/flutter_email_sender.swiftmodule/Project/arm64.swiftsourceinfo' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.framework/Modules/flutter_email_sender.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftdoc' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.framework/Modules/flutter_email_sender.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.framework/Modules/flutter_email_sender.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftdoc' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.framework/Modules/flutter_email_sender.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.framework/Modules/module.modulemap' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        warning: Stale file '/Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.framework/flutter_email_sender' is located outside of the allowed root paths.
    
        Command MergeSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code
        /Users/quentinguichot/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vibration-1.2.2/ios/Classes/VibrationPlugin.m:4:17: error: definition of 'VibrationPlugin' must be imported from module 'vibration.VibrationPlugin' before it is required
        @implementation VibrationPlugin
                        ^
        In module 'vibration' imported from /Users/quentinguichot/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vibration-1.2.2/ios/Classes/VibrationPlugin.m:2:
        /Users/quentinguichot/AndroidStudioProjects/ouiquit/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/vibration/vibration.framework/Headers/VibrationPlugin.h:3:12: note: previous definition is here
        @interface VibrationPlugin : NSObject<FlutterPlugin>
                   ^
        1 error generated.
        note: Using new build system
        note: Building targets in parallel
        note: Planning build
        note: Constructing build description
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62054777/13625305)

Comment: Take a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52478734/1227166)

Answer (score 1):

in your project's pod file, add

```
use_modular_headers!
```

and comment out use frameworks

```
use_frameworks!
```

Comment: I edit with my podfile.
I have already this


target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

Comment: Try removing use_framewoks! but keeping use_modular_headers!

Comment: It didn't work our for me, issue remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I found is to downgrade Xcode with 11.3.1 all packages ( audio player, ad mob, appreview works great ) app was validate by apple. 1 mouth loose because of .... Xcode upgrade ....