# Stale files in my Flutter Objective-C iOS projects

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

I've been experiencing issues with stale files in my Objective-C iOS projects, even though I am running the latest version of Flutter. I'm not exactly sure when this problem began, but I first noticed it while working on one of my projects. I've tried numerous methods to eliminate these stale files, but nothing seems to work. I was mostly following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52478734/xcode-10-warning-stale-file-path-to-file-is-located-outside-of-the-allowed-r) Stack Overflow post.

To further investigate the issue, I created a new project from scratch, only to discover the same problem with stale files persisting. I suspected that maybe an Xcode update had occurred without my knowledge, so I checked my Xcode version and found it to be 14.3.

In an attempt to resolve the issue, I installed Xcode version 14.2 and changed the Flutter path to use 14.2 instead. However, the stale files issue remained. I even tried creating another new project, thinking it might be different since the previous one was installed on Xcode 14.3, but I still encountered stale files.

I also observed that these stale files seem to be introduced into the project when I execute a flutter run in Visual Studio Code and then switch to Xcode to run the project. A temporary workaround I found is to remove the stale files in Xcode by using the command Cmd-Shift-K followed by Cmd-Shift-B. However, this solution is short-lived, as the issue reappears when I return to Visual Studio Code and perform another flutter run. If anyone has insights into why this is happening or a more permanent solution, it would be of great help!

[Stale Error in Xcode](https://imgur.com/a/6cApju5)

[Flutter Doctor pic](https://imgur.com/a/62Z1wFa)

Comment: You ever find a solution to this?  I am having the same issue with XCode 14.2 - I am getting over 2500 of these messages which is adding enormous time to deploy my app to a device.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not. Best workaround for me I already mentioned above. It is not that big of a deal for my project more so just annoying. If you find a solution I would love to know though!

Comment: I think my issue is related to `cordova build ios` from CLI; I think the build is creating the files that are then appearing in Xcode; just don't know how to resolve it yet.  Here is more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145808/cordova-creating-hundreds-of-xcode-14-stale-files-outside-root-paths-warnings